# Blender 2.8 Crashed and cannot reopen the project anymore

Tags: sculpting

Was simply sculpting, hid the object to start building an eye. Crashed when I showed the object back. When I tried to reopen the files, blender hangs then crashes.

When I try to reopen the file, Blender Hangs then crashed, If I try to append the only object in the mesh sub. I only see a cube.

Still, the file is more than 22 mb so it's a bit on the heavy side for 8 vertices.

[image]

Anyone got through this?

Thanks

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BLcD8bU083yNJcufL7OrRJLIt3ekldKB

UPDATE: Thanks to Brenticus I'm able to continue this little sculpt, here's an update:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Just dug around in the file a bit, there's definitely more than 8 vertices there, something around 90,000. That said, I couldn't get anything to display, even after appending the object. I dug through the Blender file option in the outliner and despite being able to see that stuff existed, I couldn't interact with it. My guess would be that your file got corrupted somehow, and I'm not sure there's any way to get it back directly.

Comment: However, blender has a number of recovery options. You can try 'recover last session' or 'recover auto save' from the file menu, or check to see if any .blend1 or .blend2 files were created where the original file is stored. If so, you can open these with blender as they are basically just backup versions.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, In fact yes I tried all of this, even tried to open with former versions of 2.8 I had stored on my PC (It even crashes quicker). Desperately tried 2.79 (duuh). Blender just Swallowed it. 

What is funny is that It was probably already unrecoverable WHILE I was working on it at some point!... May be a future version will be able to open it... Someday.

I added a screen shot of the work I was doing (I was recording the session,)

Thanks.

Comment: Well... Speaking of the recording... I checked and blender crashed (in session) exactly at the time I switched back to SCULPT mode.... May it stills tries to reopen the session in sculpt mode? Is there a way to override that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't tell you what happened exactly, I did find a way to recover your sculpt.

What seems to have happened is that somehow the object got removed, but the mesh data still stayed (I believe the technical term here would be Orphan Data). How that happened I'm not sure, but I tried appending the mesh again, and switched to the Data API view in the outliner and noticed it said 0 objects but 1 mesh.

The way to recover your object is to add another mesh object, go to the Mesh Data tab of the properties panel, and right at the top where it says the name of the object, on the left you can select different mesh data. Select the name of the object you're trying to recover and whatever mesh data the object you added had will now be replaced by the sculpted object.

Comment: Perhaps someone who knows more about this than I do can add something here. I'm not sure how a crash would manage to affect all the recovery files. If you delete the object intentionally the recovery options still work, so I'm really at a loss as to what could have happened.

Comment: This is an obscure feature... It thought at first that it was somewhere else than in Object Data but you are right, that button next to the object's name!

It simply works, I'll start to make several copies of my work from now on (like when we had softwares with one single undo), thanks a TON for your time. 

You can never get angry at blender for too long...

Comment: I wouldn't call data blocks obscure. It is widely used functionality and also well [documented](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/index.html). Also, Blender makes copies of saved files with .blend1 extensions so you don't override your work by accident and autosaves your files every 2 minutes. Go to File -> Recover Auto Save to recover them. However keep in mind pretty much any question about crashes is off topic here. Crashes are not part of Blender's functionality and are caused by bugs that need to be reported to developers since they cannot be solved here in an answer.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. OP did mention that they tried all the recovery options, and that none of them worked. Regarding the nature of this question, since it's about how Blender can recover from crashes, isn't it valid? OP wasn't asking why, just if/how they can recover their work. Is it stated somewhere what questions are and are not valid in regards to crashes?